# NoReverseMatch at Reverse for ... with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, http-redirect

I am trying understand why I get the `NoReverseMatch` error when I use the User register form that I've created:

According to my situation, I reference the relevant files/information:

I have the main urls.py file named neurorehab/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from .views import home, home_files

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),

    url(r'^', include('userprofiles.urls')),
    #Call the userprofiles/urls.py

    url(r'^(?P<filename>(robots.txt)|(humans.txt))$', home_files, name='home-files'),


]

# Response the media files only in development environment
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,}),
)
```

I have the module/application named userprofiles, in which I have the userprofiles/urls.py file of this way:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from .views import (ProfileView, LogoutView,
                AccountRegistrationView, PasswordRecoveryView,
                SettingsView)
from userprofiles.forms import CustomAuthenticationForm

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/profile/$', ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile/'),

    # Url that I am using for this case
    url(r'^register/$', AccountRegistrationView.as_view(), name='register'),

    url(r'^login/$','django.contrib.auth.views.login', {
                    'authentication_form': CustomAuthenticationForm,
                    }, name='login',
),
    url(r'^logout/$', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]
```

The url `register` call to the CBV `AccountRegistrationView` located in the userprofiles/urls.py which is so:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, get_user, authenticate
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext, loader

# Importing classes for LoginView form
from django.views.generic import FormView, TemplateView, RedirectView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, reverse_lazy

from .mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from .forms import  UserCreateForm

class AccountRegistrationView(FormView):
    template_name = 'signup.html'
    form_class = UserCreateForm

    # Is here in the success_url in where I use reverse_lazy and I get
    # the NoReverseMatch
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts/profile')
    #success_url = '/accounts/profile'

    # Override the form_valid method
    def form_valid(self, form):
        # get our saved user with form.save()
        saved_user = form.save()
        user = authenticate(username = saved_user.username,
                            password = form.cleaned_data['password1'])

        # Login the user, then we authenticate it
        login(self.request,user)

        # redirect the user to the url home or profile
        # Is here in the self.get_success_url in where I  get
        # the NoReverseMatch
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

My form class `UserCreateForm` in which I made the registration form is located in userprofiles/forms.py file and it's so:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', u'Save'))

    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','password1','password2',)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

And my template is the userprofiles/templates/signup.html file:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}Register{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div>
    {% crispy form %}
    {% csrf_token %}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

When I go to my register user form, and I pressed submit this save my user and I have it for that try redirect to profile of the user recent created, but I get this error

[image]

What may be happening to me in this case. Seem that the reverse_lazy does not work?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reverse_lazy()` function either takes view function or url name to resolve it not the url path. So you need to call it as

```
success_url = reverse_lazy('profile/')
#---------------------------^ use url name
```

However, I'm not sure if `'/'` character works in url name.

If you have to use path to resolve to an url, use [`resolve()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) function.

Comment: Thanks, in fact, the character '/' in the attribute name in the 'accounts/profile' url in userprofiles/urls.py I've remove it and works. :D